# .htaccess mod_rewrite 301 redirection problem

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

I have an web application in PHP with urls like this:
https://www.domain.com/?mod=test&act=view

My problem is that when I try to use mod_rewrite to redirect users to new link:
https://www.domain.com/view-test

I have the following rule under my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^\?mod=test&act=view$ /view-test [L,R=301]
```

If I remove the leading "?" from the above rule the redirection works but obsiouly I get a 404 error. But if I keep it nothing happens

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new rule for `view-test`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^mod=test&act=view$ /view-test [L,R=301] 

# new rule for view-test
RewriteRule ^view-test$ /index.php [L]
```

**Update:**

This works perfectly for me:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mod=test&act=view$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test-view? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^test-view/?$ /index.php [L]
```

Get the values:

```
<?php

$request = str_replace("/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$request = explode("-", $request);

print_r($request);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => view
)
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I think I didn't explained correctly... My problem is that my url is www.domain.com/?mod=test&act=view and I simply can't match the "?" char in the redirect instruction... Thanks for the reply!

Comment: That kind of works. But the last rule send me to index.php and i wanted to be redirected to index.php?mod=test&act=view. If I replace index.php with the real page I end up in a loop and getting an error. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: Ok I see that maybe I didn't explained my problem clear enough. I'll accept your answer as it works and oppening a new one so I can explain myself better. Thanks for your time. :D

Comment: hey @jribeiro yeah I really don't know what are you trying to do, I see the new post and I still don't understand, I've tested the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336227/problem-in-redirection-through-htaccess/7337383#7337383) of that post and is more weird but I'm glad that you have found the answer