# Problem in redirection through .htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a php generated file like:
http://www.domain.com/?mod=test&act=view

And I want to create a redirection from that address to something like:
http://www.domain.com/view-test

so that everytime a user (or bot) accesses the first uri it gets redirected to http://www.domain.com/view-test viewing the content of the first uri.

Right now I have the following rules under my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^view-test$ /?mod=test&act=view [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mod=test&act=view
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /view-test? [R,L]
```

The first rule creates a "page alias" and works if I delete the other two lines (but doesn't redirect my users as i want to)

After placing the last two rules I end up in a Loop or something and I get a broswer message saying "The page is not redirecting correctly"...

If I remove the first rule I get an 404 error saying /view-test could not be found

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that regex is better. Full `.htaccess` file for this situation if your php handler is `index.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mod=(\w+)&act=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^$ /%2-%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)-(\w+)$ /index.php?mod=$2&act=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

forget about .htaccess it's easier to do it in php,i use it in my site, i created an index.php file to redirect users from example.com to example.com/123

in my index.php i put this

```
<?php
header('Location: http://example.com/123');
?
>
```

Comment: PHP redirection would not work on my site because the implementation sends the headers before knowing wich module to load. Thanks anyway